# Fatal error in V8

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, debian, v8

I'm trying to deploy my Rails app to a new VPS which runs with Debian. I'm using Nginx and Phusion Passenger as my server.

I've installed Node.js as a JavaScript runtime. Sadly I'm seeing the following error message:

```
Fatal error in v8::V8::AddGCPrologueCallback()
V8 is no longer usable
```

Edit:

It is fixed now. Apparently gr security was causing the error.

Comment: You need to be more detailed. Are you running a 64-bit build? What version of v8? Can you invoke d8? Can you build v8 with symbols?

Comment: It is fixed now. Apparently gr security was causing the error.

Comment: Could you post the solution as an answer? That way others who have the same problem will know what the problem is and how to fix it. Ideally you could add what you did to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem occurs on kernels with grsecurity and certain restrictive rules.
node.js needs to exec code in certain areas of memory,where the server does not like it.

You seem to need to switch two flags for the "node" binary.
Also you might need to switch those for your ruby binary.

#### Toggle SEGMEXEC on

```
 paxctl -S `which node` && paxctl -S `which ruby`
```

#### Toggle MPROTECT off

```
 paxctl -m `which node` && paxctl -m `which ruby`
```

#### Test if node works now

```
 node -e "console.log(1+1);"
```

Fun fact is that i can now Toggle SEGMEXEC off and node still works :S... however switching it on seemed to initially fix it for me.
If it does not work, play with the flags and try the node -e

Good luck!
gizmore